# AD FS a replacement for LDS

Tags: active-directory, adfs, adfs2.0, adlds, adfs3.0

We are currently running AD LDS and using adamsync to create userproxy objects from multiple domains to allow authentication from multiple domains. The adamsync process is messy and i am curious if AD FS would be a suitable alternative? We have multiple domains and have applications that use LDAP to authenticate and would like to point our LDAP applications to AD FS and have it authenticate users from several different AD domains. Is this possible? If so is there documentation on how to set this up? We would love to be able to get rid of LDS and replace it with AD FS.

Our LDS is running on windows 2008 server
AD FS would be built on windows 2012 R2

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, as it currently stands the answer in "No".

ADFS can only authenticate against AD. You can only use LDS as an authorization source.

However, ADFS vNEXT (Server 2016) will support authentication against both SQL DB and LDAP.

You mention "multiple domains" which implies multiple AD?

Normally with ADFS, you remove the trusts at the AD level, have an ADFS for each AD domain and federate the ADFS which moves the trust to the Federation level.